# Can an RSS feed 'reference' other RSS feeds?

Tags: xml, rss

Is it possible for an RSS feed to reference other 3rd party RSS feeds?

I need to make an RSS feed that includes the feeds of hundreds of other RSS feeds. The list of feeds will be updated at least weekly.

Rather than merging them all the content together, is it possible to only include the URL of each of the feeds?

I am **not** trying to generate HTML, or do anything in a browser, just generate a valid RSS feed.

Comment: By 'reference', you  mean as a link in your RSS feed to that feed?

Comment: Yes. I would like to generate a 'master' feed that links to other feeds. The service consuming the master feed should then be able to grab all the content from child feeds.

Comment: that probably depends on the "consuming service" then, what is that?

Comment: http://www.kb.se/plikt/eplikt/metadataspecifikationer/